# Keep running into Class Variable problems in my code

Tags: java, variables

I'm playing around a little in Java, started making a client in Java code for a small chat based app.  I'm trying to make the variable `ssocket` a class variable, and it will be the variable that connects with the server (haven't written it yet, but that's not the problem).  So, I'm declaring the class variable `ssocket` right under the class declaration, and then (I keep doing and commenting this out) declaring `ssocket` as an empty socket in the constructor.  Then, in a method called `sendToSever`, I try to reference it, to set the host, port and stuff, but it keeps saying its supposed to be a local variable, instead of the class variable.  But, a few lines later in the same method, I reference it fine.  Also, when I tried setting the `ssocket` to the host and port in the constructor in a `try` block, it wasn't using the class variable either.  I want to set the socket officially in `sendToSever`, so that they can try reconnecting every time they do an action, but I can't figure out how to fix this.  If anything is not clear, I will gladly edit this post.

I have tried:

1. Setting to static
2. Fully defining ssocket in constructor (assigning real host and port to it)
3. Referencing ssocket outside of try block but still inside `sendToServer()`;

I want to declare ssocket as a class variable, and then set it if not already set in sendToServer (so that if it can't connect, the variable is still null or something, and then the next times it's called, it tries to reconnect).

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Font;
// ...
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ClientGUI extends JFrame {

    private JTextField lgntxtUsername;
    private JPasswordField lgntxtPassword;
    private JLabel lgnlblUsername;
    private JLabel lgnlblPassword;
    private JPanel SignupPanel;
    private JLabel lgnlblMAKE;
    private JLabel sgnlblImage;
    private JLabel sgnlblUsername;
    private JTextField sgntxtUsername;
    private JLabel sgnlblPassword;
    private JPasswordField sgntxtPassword;
    private JLabel sgnlblCNFPASS;
    private JPasswordField sgntxtPasswordC;
    private JButton sgnbtnSIGNUP;
    private Socket ssocket;

    // I declare the class variable above
    public ClientGUI() throws IOException {
        // define some JFrame stuff, skipping it
        // set to empty socket, though I have tried fully setting it in a try block, hadn't worked
        ssocket = new Socket();

    // More methods, don't use ssocket at all
    public int sendToServer(String text) {
        try (
            // Says it needs a declaration, doesnt register this as the class variable
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 123456);
            // Despite the error in the above line, I reference ssocket fine in the next few lines
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(ssocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ssocket.getInputStream()));) {
            out.println(text);
            return 200;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            String[] splitArray = e.toString().split(":");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitArray));
            return 500;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't ever link to your code again. Instead, fix your formatting errors so that you can properly include it. I have edited your question to include your code as it was on Pastebin.

Comment: you're missing a closing brace `}` after your constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed few issues in the code and did the changes below.

1. Make the ssocket variable as a class level
2. No need of initializing it to null inside the constructor
3. sendToServer will check if it is null before initializing it (there was a typo in this method)
4. As @xtratic has already mentioned, constructor is not properly closed.

Below is the modified code.

```
// static variable, single reference is shared across all instances of the class
private static Socket ssocket = null;

public ClientGUI() throws IOException {
    // ssocket is not initialized here
}

public int sendToServer(String text) {
    try (

        if (ssocket == null) {
            // typo, socket is used in code instead of ssocket 
            ssocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 123456);
        }
        // ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if connectivity issue occurred, you can close the ssocket and set to null here
        // ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll go try this now.  I was probably missing the `}` because I had copied and pasted badly (didn't want to copy the whole program because it's over 200 lines).

Comment: @NeuroAssassin I too assumed the missing } as a copy paste issue, anyway mentioned. Hopefully the instructions will move you forward.

Comment: Okay, looks like it worked; I had to get rid of the parentheses however, Java kept saying it was expecting curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are not closing your constructor method:

```
public ClientGUI() throws IOException {
    ssocket = new Socket();
// } should be closed her, but was not

 public int sendToServer(String text) {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, that just happened when I was copying and pasting my code over; that would've caused a lot more errors if that was it.